# How to get current visible view controller in page view controller in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am creating an app in Xamarin.IOS.

I want to get the current view controller at present in page view controller.
Please give me any example code or answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook to `DidFinishAnimating` event to get the current page view controller.

```
DidFinishAnimating += (sender, e) => {
    if (e.Completed)
    {
        var currentViewController = ((AnimalPageViewController)sender).ViewControllers[0];
    }
};
```